# Python/Pandas aggregation combined with NLTK

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, pandas, scikit-learn, nltk

I want to do some text processing on a dataset containing Twitter messages. So far I'm able to load the data (.CSV) in a Pandas dataframe and index that by a (custom) column 'timestamp'.

```
df = pandas.read_csv(f)
df.index = pandas.to_datetime(df.pop('timestamp'))
```

**Looks a bit like this:**

```
                                user_name      user_handle
timestamp
2015-02-02 23:58:42  Netherlands Startups   NLTechStartups
2015-02-02 23:58:42               shareNL         share_NL
2015-02-02 23:58:42  BreakngAmsterdamNews   iAmsterdamNews

[49570 rows x 8 columns]
```

**I can create a new object (Series) containing just the text like so:**

```
texts = pandas.Series(df['text'])
```

Which creates this:

```
2015-06-02 14:50:54    Business Update Meer cruiseschepen dan ooit in...
2015-06-02 14:50:53    RT @ProvincieNH: Provincie maakt Markermeerdij...
2015-06-02 14:50:53    Amsterdam - Nieuwe flitspaal Wibautstraat: In ...
2015-06-02 14:50:53    Amsterdam - Nieuwe flitspaal Wibautstraat http...
2015-06-02 14:50:53    Lugar secreto em Amsterdam: Begijnhof // Hidde...
Name: text, Length: 49570
```

**1. Is this new object of the same sort of type (dataframe) as my initial `df` variable, just with different columns/rows?**

Now together with the [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) tookit I'm able to `tokenize` the strings using this:

```
for w in words:
    print(nltk.word_tokenize(w))
```

This iterates the array instead of *mapping* the 'text' column to a multiple-column 'words' array. **2. How would I do this and moreover how do I then count the occurrences of each word?**

I know there is a `unique()` method which I could use to create a distinct list of words. But then again I'd need an extra column which is a count over the array which I'm unable to produce in the first place.  :) **3. Or would the next step towards 'counting' occurrences of those words be `grouping`?**

**EDIT. 3: I seem to need "[CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer)", thanks EdChum**

```
documents = df['text'].values

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=0, stop_words=[])
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)
print(X.toarray())
```

My main goal is to count the occurences of each word and selecting the **top X** results. I feel I'm on the right track, but I can't get the final steps just right..

Comment: Just to clarify you want to know how to count each word that appears in the tokenized output and also have a count of all words that appear in your df? Have you looked at [countVectoriser](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#from-occurrences-to-frequencies)?

Comment: Great suggestion. But in layman's terms: are you saying I'm better off using `scipy.sparse` matrices instead of `pandas` dataframes?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that, just that there may be already an implemented method that does what you want, is that the case?

Comment: Yes it looks like it. However the input is `file`, `filename` or `content`. I'm not savvy enough with Python to see how I need to map my existing array of texts with this class. My original data is dataframe indexed by 'timestamp'. How would I pass 'just the texts'?

Comment: It should work with just `df['text']` as a param, otherwise try `df['text'].values` to return a numpy array which should be compatible

Comment: I seem to get a 'TypeError: fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'raw_document' exception. I tried both `df['text']` as well as `.values`.  I'm calling this: `CountVectorizer.fit_transform(documents)`. I also tried this: `CountVectorizer.fit_transform(raw_documents=documents)` (this misses `self` as positional argument..).

Comment: I updated my question with my new code using a `CountVectorizer`. Is this a correct approach?

Comment: Got it! Darned syntax :)

Comment: I was about to say that I could get this to work no problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71266/discussion-between-ropstah-and-edchum).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on EdChums comments here is a way to get the (I assume global) word counts from CountVectorizer:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect= CountVectorizer()

df= pd.DataFrame({'text':['cat on the cat','angel eyes has','blue red angel','one two blue','blue whales eat','hot tin roof','angel eyes has','have a cat']\
              ,'class': ['a','a','a','a','c','c','b','e']})

X = vect.fit_transform(df['text'].values)
y = df['class'].values
```

covert the sparse matrix returned by `CountVectoriser` to a dense matrix, and pass it and the feature names to the `dataframe` constructor. Then transpose the frame and sum along `axis=1` to get the total per word:

```
word_counts =pd.DataFrame(X.todense(),columns = vect.get_feature_names()).T.sum(axis=1)
word_counts.sort(ascending=False)
word_counts[:3]
```

If all you are interested in is the frequency distribution of the words consider using `Freq Dist` from `NLTK`:

```
import nltk
import itertools
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
texts = ['cat on the cat','angel eyes has','blue red angel','one two blue','blue whales eat','hot tin roof','angel eyes has','have a cat']
texts = [nltk.word_tokenize(text) for text in texts]
# collapse into a single list
tokens = list(itertools.chain(*texts))

FD =FreqDist(tokens)
```